# Multiple User buying same item

Tags: php, paypal

I am working on a php  paypal application. I have number of tasks for which users can apply and pay using paypal. User needs to do particular payment cost for this. **When a user successfully apply for a particular task then that should not visible to others.**

I am having a task table for this  and have another table having task-user relationship(who paid for which task).

I want to know about situation when multiple users buying at one time. As you know the task should be given to a user when he completely pays.(from website checkout page to Paypal checkout page). how can I manage this ???

Also using ipn here. should i need to send parameters with return url?? Just need a upper level answer not the code level.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a reservation type system similar to ticketmaster. So when a user engages in the purchase of a specific task, you reserve that task for them for 15 minutes or however long. Insuring that they have enough time to complete the checkout process. So you would set that task to unavailable in your table while the current user is checking out, and if after 15 minutes he still hasn't completed the transaction you cancel it and make the task available again.

Comment: Thanks for replying..Yes I can flag a task as unavailable but how can i unflag it if the user just exit from here ? how can i set 15 min interval

Comment: you can have a table of reserved tasks that dumps a task after 15 minutes. when displaying tasks, don't display any that are in that table.

Comment: I don't honestly know the "standard way," but it's certainly an effective way.